# What does a successful MySQL DELETE return? How to check if DELETE was successful?

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP, I am trying to delete a record, but I want to check if it was successful or not. Is anything returned from a successful `DELETE FROM foo where bar = 'stuff'`?

Alternatively, do you know any other ways to check if a DELETE was successful? Or am I better off just making sure the row exists before I delete it? I am trying to avoid another query if possible.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Assuming you are using [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/mysql_query):

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, **DELETE**, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

If you are using [PDO::exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), then the manual says this:

> PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec() returns 0.

Don't want to answer snipe, but since this was selected as the answer, I should note that mysql_query will return `TRUE` even if the query did not actually remove anything. You should use [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/mysql_affected_rows) to check for that.

Comment: "Don't want to answer snipe" Oh no! Not my precious, precious points! =)

Comment: If you are using PDO::execute() to get the number of affected rows you should use PDO::rowCount()

Comment: Since you did include a PDO method, a mysqli_ example would also be beneficial.

Answer (score 42):

Additionally, if you care about the number of rows that were affected:

> [Use] [mysql_affected_rows()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.

Comment: Beat me! Checking that this is > 0 is helpful, as mysql_query() will return TRUE if the query was properly formed but didn't delete anything.

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you please clarify that it did not delete anything because there was nothing to delete or because of some error?

Comment: @MaxZoom If there's an error, `mysql_query` will return `FALSE`. If there's nothing to delete, `mysql_query` would return `TRUE` and `mysql_affected_rows` would be `0`. That said, you shouldn't be using `mysql_query` **at all** anymore.

Answer (score 19):

you could try this for your php code, placed after your query runs:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo "You have successfully updated your data.<br><br>";
}
else {
    echo "The data you submitted matched the current data so nothing was changed.<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For other types of **SQL** statements, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP`, etc, `mysql_query()` returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on error.