# How can I retrieve the number of rows deleted with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, so I have been using a [PDO wrapper](http://development.andrewjudd.ca/) for a project I'm working on, and I'm trying to find out whether a DELETE query was successful or not. Here is the code I am using:

```
/**
* A pretty straight-forward query to delete a row from the verification
* table where user_id is $user_id and code is $code
*/
$result = $this->database->query("DELETE FROM verification " .
                                 "WHERE user_id = %u AND code = %s",
                                 $user_id,
                                 $code);

/**
 * This function will grab the PDO's exec() return, which should
 * return the number of rows modified.
 */
if($this->database->getNumAffected($result) > 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

The problem is, whether the DELETE query actually deletes a row or not, $this->database->getNumAffected($result) always returns '0'.

You can check out the wrapper, but basically $this->database->getNumAffected($result) simply returns exactly the same value PDO::exec() would return.

I tried this code without the wrapper (directly into PDO,) and I had the same problem but reverse: it always returned '1' (whether a row was deleted or not.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922398/what-does-a-successful-mysql-delete-return-how-to-check-if-delete-was-successful) SO question, I'm doing everything right... I don't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as you expect because the 'wrapper' that you're using doesn't ever use PDO::exec() - it wraps **everything** in a PDO statement. According to a quick read of the source code for version 2.2.6 of the 'database' class from the URL you provided, the 'query' method should return an array which contains the statement handle:

```
502 $statement = $this -> getDatabaseConnection () -> prepare ( $query );
...
587 $ret = array ( $statement, func_get_args (), $lastIndex );
588     
589 return ( $ret );
```

So, assuming your `$this->database->query()` is calling this database class' `query` method, you should be able to do `$result[0]->rowCount()`.

Note that your assertion to the earlier response that "the wrapper that [you are] using uses a different version of rowCount() because of an error that exists with the rowCount() function" is not true - the wrapper implements a numRows, but this is not the same thing as [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/pdostatement.rowcount), which is intact inside of the statement handle returned from `database::query()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it doesn't use exec(), hit Ctrl + F and type execute (. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I mean that it doesn't use PDO::exec(), but uses PDOStatement::execute(), which is an entirely different thing. It'd probably be useful to go to php.net/pdo and learn the difference between the PDO object (and its 'exec()' method) and the PDOStatement object (and its 'execute()' method). There are some really critical differences there.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. Thanks very much for the answer, and I will look into that. I don't know that much about PDO, as when I started learning it (which was prompted by the person who made this wrapper,) I was immediately given a wrapper to use instead. The only advantage of the wrapper I see is that you have to type variables, so if it's the wrong type (e.g. a string when it should be an integer,) it returns an error.

Oh, I meant to say this in my first comment: I understand that numRows() is very different from rowCount(), and because of the way numRows() works, I don't use it.

Answer (score 11):

```
$query = $this->database->prepare("DELETE FROM verification WHERE user_id = :user_id AND code = :code", array('user_id' => $user_id, 'code' => $code));
$query->execute();

if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
  return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

Comment: Hmm, the wrapper that I am using uses a different version of rowCount() because of an error that exists with the rowCount() function. The numRows() in the wrapper simply does a SELECT COUNT(*) query, so this will not work for the wrapper.