# mysql error code to check delete went through

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a successful MySQL DELETE return? How to check if DELETE was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922398/what-does-a-successful-mysql-delete-return-how-to-check-if-delete-was-successful)

Hello,

If I run a delete query, what is the php/mysql error code returned if a row was actually found and deleted or not found (and hence not deleted)?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922398/what-does-a-successful-mysql-delete-return-how-to-check-if-delete-was-successful

Comment: Duplicate of what Rocket linked.

Comment: FWIMC:  I read that before making this.  It was too complex for me, and I like the answers given here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can examine [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) for that. But there no function, that can tell you which specific rows were updated or deleted by previous DML statement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the error code. Call [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).