# Mysql PHP Query Runs Perfectly, But returns as false

Tags: php, mysql

I have some mysql_query()s that work just fine, but if I put them in an if else statement they return false. Any idea?

```
        public function delete_post() {

        $id = $_GET['post_id'];

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='$id' LIMIT 1");

        if ( !mysql_query() ) {
            echo ('Could not be Deleted');
        } else { 
            echo 'Deleted Successfully'; 
        }
    }
```

and when i run it, it deletes the post, but returns "Could not be deleted"

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Set the query as a variable, and use the variable for your `if()` statement.

Comment: Just a side note, the return of `mysql_query` only returns `true/false` on the success of the SQL query, not if anything was changed after the execution ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running a query with an empty SQL statement, which is not correct SQL. Try this.

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE ...");
if (!$result) {
    echo ('Could not be Deleted');
} else {
    echo 'Deleted Successfully';
}
```

The difference is on line 2 (of my code).

Comment: You didn't spot the SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated. You really should use [PDO::query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) instead.

**If you still wish to use it, do:**

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='$id' LIMIT 1");
if (!$result) 
{
    echo ('Could not be Deleted');
}
```

**Explanation:**

In you original code you call `mysql_query()` two times. The second time, there is no argument, so it doesn't work, and that's what your code is reporting.

Comment: Thanks's Both of them works :)I was just dumb.. I wanted to do it the shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a pretty similar question / answer: [What does a successful MySQL DELETE return? How to check if DELETE was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922398/what-does-a-successful-mysql-delete-return-how-to-check-if-delete-was-successfu)

Can you try what it suggests and see if that will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
public function delete_post() {

        $id = $_GET['post_id'];

        $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='$id' LIMIT 1");

        if ( !$query ) {
            echo ('Could not be Deleted');
        } else { 
            echo 'Deleted Successfully'; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't spot the SQL injection.