# Delete all rows from mySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete, truncate

I want to delete all rows in a table by clicking on a Button in PHP. I have used this code

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="delet" id="delet" value="DELETE WHOLE DATA"/>
</form>
<br></br>
<?php

  //if($_GET){
  if(isset($_GET['delet'])){

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql = "DELETE  FROM tfinal";
    $sql1=mysql_query($sql, $link);
    if (mysql_query( $sql1)) {
      echo "Database dqqwewrw was successfully dropped\n";
    } else {
      echo 'Error dropping database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    }
  }
?>
```

but after ruining it says: `Error dropping database: Query was empty`
Any idea regarding overcome this problem

Comment: You don't use `DELETE` to remove a table, you use `DROP TABLE`.  `DELETE` is for deleting rows from a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="delet" id="delet" value="DELETE WHOLE DATA"/>
</form>
<br></br>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['delet'])){
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'testlo');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM tbl_fordelete';
    $sql1=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if ($sql1) {
        echo "Database dqqwewrw was successfully dropped\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Error dropping database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    }
    $connection->close();
}
```

Comment: This code isn't "dropping a database", thankfully... it's deleting records from a  table.  Also btw, deleting all records from a table is also known as [truncating](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html).

Answer (score 4):

1. Stop using `mysql_*` - it is [officially deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli) and [vulnerable to injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Switch to using `mysqli_*` or PDO prepared statements.
2. `DELETE` is for deleting rows; `DROP` is for deleting tables. Your SQL query should look like:

   ```
   $sql = "DROP TABLE `tablename`";
   ```
3. You are running the query twice - once in `$sql1 = mysql_query(...)` and once again in `if(mysql_query(...))`. For a `DROP` or `DELETE` query, [it will return `TRUE` on success and `FALSE` on error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues).
4. The second time you run the query (`if(mysql_query(...))`) you are querying the result of the first query (`$sql1`) and not the query itself (`$sql`). You should instead write:

   ```
   if(mysql_query($sql)){
   ```

   ...but in PDO/`mysqli_` format instead.

---

*References:*

- [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_query($sql1)) {
```

That is wrong. $sql1 is returned by a mysql_query(), so it is NOT a query, but a result.

related: [What does a successful MySQL DELETE return? How to check if DELETE was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922398/what-does-a-successful-mysql-delete-return-how-to-check-if-delete-was-successfu)

Answer (score 1):

Do following changes:

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="delet" id="delet" value="DELETE WHOLE DATA"/>
</form>
<br></br>
<?php

  //if($_GET){
  if(isset($_GET['delet'])){

    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql = "DROP TABLE tfinal";
    //$sql1=mysql_query($sql, $link);
    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
      echo "Database dqqwewrw was successfully dropped\n";
    } else {
      echo 'Error dropping database: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want delete your table, first, you should create table temporary
example:

```
$i="i";$joined=$i.$numCar;
        $sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE $joined (
                id  INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                km INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                gas INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                comment TEXT NOT NULL,
                date VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
                workId INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
                damage TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
                image1 VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
                image2 VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL)";
```

and after you can delete the table, example:

```
$i="i";$joined1=$i.$numberCar;$sql = "DELETE FROM '$joined1'";mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

You must have the DROP privilege for each table.
the link that explain better:
[mySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html)