# PHP else not working

Tags: php

Why my last else `$msg` is not working ? Even I do this correct. Please help and fix my issue.

**Code:**

```
 //Cancel button start
 if (isset($_POST['cncl'])) {
     $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE Email_ID='$email' AND token='$token' AND isEmailConfirmed='PENDING' AND isMobileConfirmed='PENDING'";
     ///     
     if ($con - > query($sql) === TRUE) {
         $msg = "<div class='alert-box success'><span>Registration cancelled. < /
         span > < /div > ";
     } else {
         $msg = "<div class='alert-box warning'><span>Registration cancelled! Please signup again if you create again!</span> < /
         div > ";
     }

     ///
 }
 //Cancel button end
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what does happen? `0` rows deleted will be `true` because it isn't an error. You also should parameterize your query.

Comment: When I hit button then delete row based by query. It's good and working . But my Issue Is show else or error msg when user already deleted that row and when he again hit button then he will show error msg that like this `you have already done this action` might that's why I uses else..

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922398/what-does-a-successful-mysql-delete-return-how-to-check-if-delete-was-successfu

Comment: Not helpful.. could u help pls share your code

Comment: use mysqli_affected_rows($con);

Comment: If you've read what Andrey posted you'll know that it is helpful. Do a `var_dump($con->query($sql)); die;` before `if ($con - > query($sql) === TRUE) {` and tell us what you see.

Comment: That code will give "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '>' because you miswrote the `T_ARROW` as `- >` when it has to be `->`.

Comment: @Gordon Looks like that was just a bad edit, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50902506/revisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check, Is record delete or not.

```
if (isset($_POST['cncl'])) {
     $result = $con->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE Email_ID='$email' AND token='$token' AND isEmailConfirmed='PENDING' AND isMobileConfirmed='PENDING'");
     ///     
     if ((mysql_affected_rows($con) > 0) ) {
         $msg = "<div class='alert-box success'><span>Registration cancelled. < /
         span > < /div > ";
     } else {
         $msg = "<div class='alert-box warning'><span>Registration cancelled! Please signup again if you create again!</span> < /
         div > ";
     }
```

if it will return value more than 0 then record deleted or if it will return 0 then record not delete.

Comment: Error when use your script shows `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_affected_rows()`

Comment: Which connection method you are using? mysql, mysqli or pdo?

Comment: Where from you learn yaar..Tell me the school name..How I get admission there? In india..Looks you are from india.

Comment: Yes i'm Indian. I'm not learn this from school,  Is this answer is helpful for you?

Comment: No.bexiuse when I update this error is arrive here please look https://pastebin.com/Gr3wmZpw my pastebin here here at last `else` not working and show link expire alert only. Show other message when user delete the row and when he click submit button show error message instead `session expired`

Comment: @rawathemant `mysql_*` functions should not be suggested/recommended anymore. If they are needed a note should be added that it is likely to not work in the future.

Comment: You can use mysqli_* instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysqli->query()` with a `SELECT` statement returns an instance of `mysqli_result`. It is not identical to true `(=== true)`, but nor does it represent an error.

Moreover, `$result` is undefined.you can try this

```
if (isset($_POST['cncl'])) {
     $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE Email_ID='$email' AND token='$token' AND isEmailConfirmed='PENDING' AND isMobileConfirmed='PENDING'";
     ///     
     if (($result = $con->query($sql)) !== FALSE) {
         $msg = "<div class='alert-box success'><span>Registration cancelled. < /
         span > < /div > ";
     } else {
         $msg = "<div class='alert-box warning'><span>Registration cancelled! Please signup again if you create again!</span> < /
         div > ";
     }

     ///
 }
```

Comment: When I use your code it's not show error message when I delete the row.. it means nothing happens..Same as my question

Comment: `$result` is not in the question. The OP is not using a `SELECT`.